# Problems with Scanner - Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to have the option of reading a string with multiple words, ie. Los Angeles or New York City. Using scanner.next() for "Departure" and "Arrival" would only read the first one if there were two words and split them between variables. nextLine() has not been much luck either. Here's my code:

```
            System.out.print("\nEnter flight number: ");
            int flightNumber = Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextLine());
            System.out.print("\nEnter departing city: ");
            String departingCity = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.print("\nEnter arrival city: ");
            String arrivalCity = scanner.nextLine();
```

I know it's something simple but I haven't figured it out.

Here's the input/output w/ the code above:

Enter flight number: 29

Enter departing city: (immediately it skips to the next line)

Enter arrival city:

---- What I'm really going for ----

Enter flight number: 29

Enter departing City: Los Angeles (be able to type multiple words without it skipping the next input)

Enter arrival city: Kansas City

Comment: What do you expect your input to look like?  That is, how will your input be delimited?  Enumerate all the possibilities and then it would be possible to determine how to use scanner to do this, or even if scanner is suitable at all.

Comment: Please show what your current input/output is and what your input/output should be.  That would be very helpful.:)

Comment: @skaffman, the edits you made to the original post make it difficult to identify what the problem was before the code was fixed.  @tim was calling `nextInt()` and then `nextLine()`, and this combination caused the parsing issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is that next() does not read the carriage return and it gets automatically read by your next next() or nextLine(). Use nextLine() all time and convert input to integer:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("\nEnter flight number: ");
    int flightNumber = Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextLine());
    System.out.print("\nEnter departing city: ");
    String departingCity = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.print("\nEnter arrival city: ");
    String arrivalCity = scanner.nextLine();

}
```

Comment: I switched everything to nextLine and changed the int as you have above... if i have the int first i get a NumberFormatException and if I stick it in a different position it skips over either the arrival or departure input.

Comment: @tim: post a small compilable example of your problem as the code you're showing may not be the code causing the problem.

Comment: Creating a small compilable program actually caused me to find the problem. I had a scanner.nextInt() above the loop that was throwing everything off. Completely overlooked it. Thanks!

Comment: @time I just ran your code and it worked perfectly fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

`Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine())` would also work--it returns an int, while `Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextLine())` returns an `Integer`.

As an alternative to @Edwin Dalorzo's suggestion, you can call `nextInt()` to grab the next token from the input stream and [try to convert it to an int](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29).  This method will throw an `InputMismatchException` if conversion to an int was unsuccessful.  Otherwise, it will grab **only the int value entered**.  Calling `nextLine()`, will then grab anything else that was entered in the line after the int.  In addition, `nextLine()` will **consume the newline character** added when the user pressed "enter" to submit the input (it will advance past it and discard it).

If you want to be sure that the user didn't enter anything *except* an int before pressing "Enter," call `nextInt()` first and then make sure the value of `nextLine()` is empty.  If you don't care about anything entered in the line after the int, you can ignore what `nextLine()` returns but should still call that method to consume the newline character.

Search StackOverflow for "java scanner next" or "java scanner nextLine" to find threads on this subject.