# Scanner Stops Working and Println Problems, Why?

Tags: java, eclipse, console, java.util.scanner, println

I'm using eclipse for this project. I've tried compiling in command prompt but the same problems happen. The scanner works until I get to "phone" and then it just seems to skip the user input and prints everything else on the same line.

I expect to store the users input into the assigned variables, and then print them out on separate lines.

I added `sc.close;` to see if that would help but it didn't. Some help would be greatly appreciated. Also my variable "address" isn't completely printed out. 
I think I may be using Scanner incorrectly?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class ContactDisplay {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Write a program that displays your name, address, and telephone number;
    //create scanner
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    //Creates the variables; 
    String name; 
    String address; 
    String phone; 

    //Asks for name
    System.out.print("What is your name? ");
    //stores the name
    name = sc.next(); 
    //Asks and stores the address
    System.out.print("What is your address? ");
    address = sc.next(); 
    //Asks and stores the phone number 
    //PROBLEM IS BELOW
    System.out.print("What is your phone number? ");
    phone = sc.next(); 


    //Prints everything out
    System.out.println(name);
    System.out.println(address);
    System.out.println(phone);

}
```

}

Here is a screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: do you get any error ?

Comment: No errors, it just terminates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use 'sc.nextLine()' to  scan string values, and you should use 'sc.nextInt' to scan integer values. If you press ctrl and space keys while typing a bunch of code it shows you the possible things you may want to write.

Comment: You are a genius! I would upvote your answer but I do not have enough reputation yet. Would you happen to know why "sc.next()" didn't work and why "sc.nextLine()" did? 

The output was returned as expected. http://i.imgur.com/8QiLNp6.png

Comment: because, you entered your variables as string and if you want to scan string variables you must use scanner(which you named before).nextLine();

Comment: I see, thank you. If a reddcoin tipping platform was on here I'd give you some reddcoin.

Comment: You can ask me your questions, whenever you want, I m glad to answer your questions :)

Comment: @JohnnyMeza since this can be another way to implement your code but does not answer why u pump into such an issue at all?

Comment: @JohnnyMeza: Also check; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784540/problems-with-scanner-java?rq=1