# How is a.charAt(i) out of bound? What is missing?

Tags: java

So the first int of the scanner was fine. But when I type in the next line, the system told me that it was out of bound at  `if (a.charAt(i)==b.charAt(i))`. How can something comparative be out of bound?

```
    Scanner k = new Scanner(System.in);
    int length = k.nextInt();
    String a = k.nextLine();
    String b = k.nextLine();
    String c = " ";
    String d;

    for (int i = 0; i<length; i++){
        if (a.charAt(i)==b.charAt(i)){
            d = "0";
        } else {
            d = "1";
        }
        c = c+d;
    }
```

Comment: What three values did you enter in that lead to that error?

Comment: 8 was fine for the first, GGHGGHGH is when it gives me the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to get rid of the line terminator from your `nextInt()` call by calling `nextLine()`.  That is the actual source of your problem. It is still in the input buffer and is causing the following `nextLine()` to read in an empty line.  Then I recommend you modify your code to do a check to verify the lengths.

```
Scanner k = new Scanner(System.in);
    int length = k.nextInt();
    k.nextLine(); // get rid of lingering line terminator.
    String a = k.nextLine();
    String b = k.nextLine();

    if (a.length() != length && b.length() != length) {
        System.out.println("Inconsistent or incorrect lengths");
        return; // assumes you are in main
    }     


    String c = " ";
    String d;

    for (int i = 0; i<length; i++){
        if (a.charAt(i)==b.charAt(i)){
            d = "0";
        } else {
            d = "1";
        }
        c = c+d;
    }
```

Check this out for a more detailed explanation of the [Scanner issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784540/problems-with-scanner-java)

Answer (score 0):

'Out of bounds' generally means that you're asking for an item that is outside of the actual size. For example, if you ask for the 3rd item from an array that is only two items in length.

In this case, you are asking for a character that is outside of the length of the string.

If `length` is larger than the real length of either `a` or `b`, you will get this error.

Answer (score 0):

You are making an assumption that both a and b are both longer than `length` characters.  The issue isn't that the comparable is out of range, but when you try to index at at a particular point in one or the other strings there is an out of range error.